# Reserving memory for entire python script

Tags: python, memory

I need to reserve a chunk of memory for my python application in Linux. I'm monitoring processes on Debian and I need to protect my script from other processes running wild, specifically Chrome. When there's a memory bug in Chrome or an HTML5 page, Chrome will eat up all the ram taking everything down with it including my monitor script. Is there a way to reserve a certain amount of memory so my script can still function if Chrome does eat up all available ram?

Thanks!

Stephen

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1026708/is-there-a-way-to-reserve-some-ram-for-a-process-to-prevent-it-from-becoming-unr

Comment: This is a year and a half late but thanks @GrzegorzBokota. I launch Chrome from within my script using cgroups and it has made a world of difference. I'm grateful!